# Set ID of each line on a link in a dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a page that lists all from my Post table, it looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <h:dataTable id="grid1" value="#{postControle.lista}" var="post1">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText style="float: left; font-weight: bold;" value="Titulo"/></f:facet>
                #{post1.titulo}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText style="float: left; font-weight: bold;" value="Texto"/></f:facet>
                #{post1.texto}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText style="float: left; font-weight: bold;" value="Opções"/></f:facet>
                <a href="#{postControle.requestManager('alterar',post1.id)}">Alterar</a> |
                <a href="#{postControle.requestManager('consultar',post1.id)}">Consultar</a>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </p>
</body>
```

What i want is that, at the end of each line, 2 links, one for update and other for show actions get the id of that specific post, but as it is its setting every id as the last resault of the list. How can i fix that?

Edit: Heres the HTML generated:

```
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>TODO supply a title</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <p><table id="grid1"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="col"><span style="float: left; font-weight: bold;">Titulo</span></th> 
                    <th scope="col"><span style="float: left; font-weight: bold;">Texto</span></th> 
                    <th scope="col"><span style="float: left; font-weight: bold;">Opções</span></th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        testeZ
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        asdasdsa
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        asdsadsad
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        ddddd
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        dddd
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>                     
                    </td> 
                    <td>                     
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>                     
                    </td> 
                    <td>                    
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td> 
                        dsakhgdsail
                    </td> 
                    <td> 
                        woaiuheaoiusrhjgsohrspuiohpousrhpiojnojho
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href="./faces/alterar.xhtml">Alterar</a> |
                        <a href="./faces/consultar.xhtml">Consultar</a></td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </p> 
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide the generated HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what you want to do at the end, but why don't you use a `<h:commandLink>` (that will generate a `<a>` HTML tag) instead (don't forget to nest your `<h:datatable>` in a `<h:form>`)?

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    ...
    <h:dataTable id="grid1" value="#{postControle.lista}" var="post1">
        ...
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText style="float: left; font-weight: bold;" value="Opções"/></f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{postControle.alterar}" value="Alterar"/>
            <h:commandLink action="#{postControle.consultar}" value="Consultar"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Then, you define two actions in your Java bean (the `String` returned defines the navigation case to apply after the execution of the method):

```
public String alterar() {
    ...
}

public String consultar() {
    ...
}
```

And in each action method, you can retrieve the corresponding element (i.e. `post1`) using the [`getRowData()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowData%28%29) method of the `HtmlDatatable` component:

```
public String alterar() {
    HtmlDatatable table = (HtmlDatatable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("myForm:id1");
    YourClass element = (YourClass) table.getRowData();
    ...
```

Comment: I want to use links, not buttons. Its a datatable listing all posts from the db table, what i want from it is, through links in each line, send the user to the show/update page of that specific post(the post of that line).

Comment: @onildo my answer works also for links. Replace the commandButton component by a commandLink.

Comment: @onildo I've edited my answer in order to use a `commandLink`, so it will fits your requirements now...